# How can I start a 256 color game on a Virtual Machine with Win XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, virtual-machine, colors

(Note: I am from Germany and have my system on german language, so if i my translations of the Buttons and stuff i get on screen seem strange to you pls let me know)

I wanted to play a old pc game of mine. But when I want to start it, the only way is by changing in 256 color mode. As I don't run the game in fullscreen, my desktop and stuff i have on screen look crappy.
So I decided to install a Virtual Machine (Windows XP Mode - Virtual PC). I installed the game there and tried to run it. Now the VM told me to change to 256 colors, which I did, by setting the Property "Start with 256 colors" in the ".exe".
But that doesn't seem to work. Error is always "Desktop depth is higher then 8bit. Please reconfigure your system for 256 colors.
No Problem I thought, so I wanted to change the whole VM to 256 colors (I don't care if this window alone looks crappy). But the given tecnique (as seen here [How can I set the color depth to 8-bit in Windows XP?](https://superuser.com/questions/211522/how-can-i-set-the-color-depth-to-8-bit-in-windows-xp)) does not work, as i can#t click the "advanced" Button as described in this method.

Now I am totally lost. And don't know what to do.
I either want all the whole VM in 256 colors or the program running in 256 colors compatibility.
(Btw. I tried all compatibility modes - did not change anything)
Thx for any tips

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please don't add solutions to the question. Instead, post it as an answer (click "answer your question") which can be voted on. Remember to come back to your question two days later to accept your answer, unless someone else posts a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP Mode on Virtual PC uses some of the configurations of the "upper" System. If you deactivate the integration of these functionalities, you can change the color depth to 256 colors in the Windows XP Mode. Basically you have to *Disable Integration Features* in the *Tools* menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, I'm using Windows XP VM in UTM and the graphics drivers installed as default by UTM SPICE do not support 256-colour mode. So you have to edit the VM to select another (eg. CIRRUS) graphics driver that does support 256-colours.